# How do I split a long PL/pgSQL line of code over multiple lines?

Tags: postgresql-9.4

Is there a way to split a long line of PL/pgSQL code over multiple lines? My context is a trigger function where I log inserts into a table as per:

```
INSERT INTO insert_log (log_time, description)
VALUES (
    now()
    , 'A description. Made up of 3 semi long sentences. That I want to split, in the code, not in the log table, over 3 lines for readability.'
);
```

Comment: That is plain SQL, not PL/pgSQL

Comment: I only included the chunk that I needed help with, it's part of a PL/pgSQL function.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

String constants can be split over multiple lines [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

```
INSERT INTO insert_log (log_time, description)
VALUES (
    now()
    , 'A description. Made up of 3 semi long sentences. '
      'That I want to split, in the code, not in the log table, '
      'over 3 lines for readability.'
);
```